# Do web browsers check the hosts file before refering to their DNS cache?

Tags: domain-name-system

On a client machine such as OSX or Windows:

Do web browsers check the hosts file before refering to their DNS cache?

I am trying to figure out the full DNS 'route' in my mind.

- Hosts File
- Browser DNS Cache
- Local DNS Cache
- DNS Server
- Root Hints or Forwarding

Does it differ between browsers and OSs?

Comment: It is OS dependant. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ideally I would like to know how it differs between OSs, primarily OSX and Win10 - I was wondering if Firefox or Edge might do these in a different order.

Comment: its not up to the browser.. the browser just makes a OS call. so its up to the OS in question. Now some browsers can have plugins to ignore them but its something you'd have to install

Comment: I know at least some if not all browsers have their own DNS cache separate from the operating systems cache in order to improve user experience/speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers generally do not do anything except asking the IP library of the operating system to resolve a host name. So the normal behavior of ANY IP based program applies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on UNIX systems like me on Debian, the first thing which is checked is the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: While this is usually the case, it's actually configurable. `man nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows machine, hosts file entries are loaded into the DNS cache.